# Format JS date.toLocaleString differently

Tags: javascript, date

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)


console.log(`streak=0; expires=${date.toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'long', day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' })}`);
```

In my output, I get
streak=0; expires=Sunday, January 2, 2022

My question is:

How can I format the date like this:

Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC

(12 and UTC don't need to be included)

I want the date number to go first then the month, not the other way around.

I am doing this because I need it to be formatted like that for a cookie:

document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";

(w3schools)

Tell me if that's not how you use cookies.

Comment: There are many, many questions and answers on [how to format a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date). Try `new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB',{year:'numeric',month:'short', weekday:'short', day:'numeric'}))` gives "Wed, 5 Jan 2022" for me. But note that's local, not UTC.

Comment: FYI, for `HTTP-date` formats, see https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#preferred.date.format